# Error trying to find exec "cc1d"

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++

I'm trying to compile and run a c++ program from eclipse-c++. Unfortunately, I'm running into quite a few errors. I'm running Linux Mint 17.

My latest error occurs after building, but before the program runs. It seems g++ can't find the executable "cc1d." I've looked on the internet for a solution, but all questions seem to be asking about a missing executable called "cc1." I tried installing `gcc-c++` from my package distributor, but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried making a symbolic link pointing to the program "cc." I named the link "cc1d," and it kind worked, but numerous options specified by g++ didn't work when I did that.

Actual error message:
`g++: error trying to exec 'cc1d': execvp: No such file or directory`

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: cc1d is part of gcd, a compiler for the D language. It's rather hard to figure out what you've installed on your system and what you've done in eclipse to make this happen though....

Comment: @nos I have g++and gcc installed. Otherwise I just downloaded eclipse from the website and ran it. I don't see gcd in my package distributor. What is it named?

Comment: Well, you have to have done more than just running eclipse, such as importing an existing project, or creating a new projects somehow. It's possible you've somehow made eclipse compile a file ending with .d. The D compiler is probably called gdc, not gcd - I had a spelling error there.

Comment: Ok, I did create a new project and the file I want to run does end with .d. Is that my problem?

Comment: Yes, C++ files are identified by having a .cpp, a .cxx or a .C extension (the latter is a capital C), and a few others, but certainly not a .d extension

Comment: @nos that was it. The file ended with .d. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the gcc manual:

> C++ source files conventionally use one of the suffixes .C, .cc,
>   .cpp, .CPP, .c++, .cp, or .cxx; C++ header files often use .hh or .H;
>   and preprocessed C++ files use the suffix .ii.  GCC recognizes files
>   with these names and
>          compiles them as C++ programs even if you call the compiler the same way as for compiling C programs (usually with the name gcc).

So to identify the code as C++, the source code files must have any of the above mentioned extensions, and not any other extensions such as .D